# A `try catch //this is a workaround` in the method. How should it be rewrtten?

Tags: java, try-catch

A project source code has a Java method for SQL handling. The method does work, but it uses a questionable workaround: `try-catch` block at the very end of the method for normal execution. What is the correct way to implement it?

```
    public void run() {
        if (running) {
            return;
        }
        running = true;            
        while(null == Common.server || null == Common.database || !ConnectionsPool.isInitialized()) {
            // Wait until the database is set before continuing...
            try {
                Thread.sleep(1000);
            }
            catch(Exception ex) {}
        }
        while(running) {
            final Connections cs = ConnectionsPool.getConnections();
            Connection  c  = null;
            while(!entries.isEmpty()) {
                if (null == c) {
                    c = cs.getConnection();
                }
                SQLLogEntry entry = entries.remove();
                if (null != entry) {
                    try {
                        write(entry, c); //find usages
                    }
                    catch (SQLException ex) {
                        writeLogFile("Could not write entry to SQL", ex);
                    }
                }
            }
            if (null != c) {
                try {
                    c.commit();
                }
                catch (SQLException ex) {
                    writeLogFile("Could commit to SQL", ex);
                    try {
                        c.rollback();
                    }
                    catch (SQLException ex1) {
                    }

                    // log
                    final StringWriter err = new StringWriter();                        
                    ex.printStackTrace(new PrintWriter(err));
                    EditorTransactionUtil.writeLogFile(err.toString());                        
                    // for user
                    final String msg = "Exception: " + EditorUtil.getErrorMessage(ex.getMessage());                        
                    try {
                        SwingUtilities.invokeAndWait(() -> {
                            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, msg);
                        });
                    }
                    catch (Throwable ex1) {
                    }
                }
                finally {
                    cs.returnConnection(c);
                }
                c = null;
            }

            synchronized(entries) {
                try {
                    entries.wait(1000);
                }
                catch (InterruptedException ex) {
                    // This is a workaround to process this loop...
                }
            }
        }
        writeLogFile("SQLMsgLogger run loop stopping...");
    }
```

Comment: Wich try-catch block do you mean? There are a lot of them... Also maybe StackOverflow is not the best community to ask for code recommendation/reviewing.

Comment: Somewhere else `entries` is probably reassigned / called `entries.notify()` or such, synchronized. I do not know what `entries` is, but some concurrent capable queue should be used. That entire synchronized block should disappear.

Comment: This one: `catch (InterruptedException ex) { // This is a workaround to process this loop...}`

Comment: The catch block will never be executed because you don't call Thread.interrupt() on it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Problems with this code start here.

```
If(running) return;
running=true;
```

This is clearly an attempt to make sure that only one thread executes. This is a wrong way to check concurrency. Second tread might kick in right when `if` check ended, but assignment didn't start yet. You need to use syncronizible interface.

As for the disposed try catch block - as Konrad pointed out it will not be executed without `Thread.interrupt()` call. It might be dead code left from previous versions.